# Percentage color hue recognition

Tags: c#, image-processing

I've found a nice applet http://www.bethleedesign.com/testing/project3/index1.php where I can see the percentage distribution of the each color on the image. How can I do it in C# ? Any known library ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about already existing methods but it's very easy to write your own.

Just load the bitmap to memory and check the color of each pixel.

If color is not in list - add it to the counters list.

After that just delete each counter value on global pixels count.

P.S.
Try to check the following project source code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C